# Device not configured after sshfs attempt

Tags: macos-sierra, user-profile, tunnel, ssh-tunnel

After using sshfs on my Mac I am no longer able to see my user directory.

When I open a terminal window I see the following:

```
Last login: Mon May 22 10:54:30 on ttys003
mkdir: /Users/<username>/.bash_sessions: Device not configured
-bash: /Users/<username>/.bash_profile: Device not configured
touch: /Users/<username>/.bash_sessions/35166655-583B-47CC-9BCF-5E785DD5E46E.historynew: Device not configured
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I used to use `sshfs` and got this error; the only way to fix it I found without rebooting  was:

```
sudo diskutil umount force /path/to/mount
```

I've recently been trying https://github.com/spion/adbfs-rootless for something else and find I can get into the same situation, the "fix" works in that case as well.

Comment: Then you have too run `sshfs` again to re-mount it. Worked for me, thanks.

Comment: Running macOS 10.15.7 I had to use the full path for the command, e.g.
`sudo /usr/sbin/diskutil umount force /path/to/mount`

Comment: As it happens I'm running into this very same problem. Unfortunately, `sudo diskutil umount force /my/mount/path/` gives 'Unmount failed for <path>'. Any other remedy besides a full reboot?

Comment: Update on my previous comment, in case it benefits anyone else: to my own surprise it did work with the following command: `umount -f /my/mount/path`  The path was now unmounted and I could move or delete it. Not sure what the difference is between this and `diskutil umount force` but somehow it did the trick 

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't getting anywhere so took a chance and did a reboot. Everything seems to be OK now.

Comment: You can fix it without rebooting, see my answer.